# How to change PYTHONPATH for Anaconda and Windows 7?

Tags: python, anaconda, pythonpath

So my PYTHONPATH is set to a folder I don't want it set to. How do I change it?

In Anaconda Prompt I've tried:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\NewLocation
```

But every time I do this PYTHONPATH is reset when I reopen Anaconda.

Comment: That answer doesn't work for Anaconda.....

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONPATH can be changed used regedit.

For me there are multiple potential locations for pythonpath:

Look in:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\PYTHONPATH
- HKEY_USERS\Environment\PYTHONPATH
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Python\PythonCore\PythonPath
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Python\ContinuumAnalytics\Anaconda27-64\PythonPath

Or use Edit->Search-> "PythonPath"

Answer (score -1):

The correct command is

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\NewLocation
```

You have missed the '=' sign.

Comment: It's still not working. PYTHONPATH is reset every time I close anaconda prompt.

Comment: In that case, you have to modify the Environment Variables under System Properties.